# How to style/disable the "Loading..." text in the monaco editor?

Tags: css, monaco-editor

I have searched around for this but haven't found anything, and it is too sudden to be able to inspect what CSS class is being used to show this. Any idea how to remove it? It is a quick flash of "Loading..." text in the center.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source code for @monaco-editor/react, there is a `loading={null}` property you can use :]